# What are some examples of Walt and Jesse taking on attributes of the foils that they kill?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* Walt seems to take on attributes of the foils that he kills. For instance:

1. After Walt kills Crazy 8, he starts cutting the crust off of
   sandwiches.
2. After Walt kills Gus, he starts greeting people from the drug
   underworld who visit him in his place of employment as though they
   are regular customers.

What other examples have people seen?